# Powershell does not recognize module

Tags: ruby, powershell, vagrant

The following is a problem that I have using Vagrant 1.7.2, Ruby and Powershell, however I think is a general problem using Powershell versions.

When I run this command from Cmd or Poweshell console or ISE it works

```
powershell -version 4.0 -command {import-module C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\SmbShare\SmbShare.psd1}
```

When I run it inside ruby IRB as follows it also works

```
system('powershell -version 4.0 -noprofile -file PsTest.ps1')
```

Nonetheless, when I ran it within Vagrant that uses Ruby

```
-version : The term '-version' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
```

If I take out the -version parameter I get

```
import-module : The specified module 'C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\SmbShare\SmbShare.
psd1'
```

I think is it trying to use powershell 1.0, but from within the script I use `$PSVersionTable` and it all cases I got the same

```
Key   : PSVersion
Value : 4.0

Key   : WSManStackVersion
Value : 3.0

Key   : SerializationVersion
Value : 1.1.0.1

Key   : CLRVersion
Value : 4.0.30319.42000

Key   : BuildVersion
Value : 6.3.9600.17400

Key   : PSCompatibleVersions
Value : {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}

Key   : PSRemotingProtocolVersion
Value : 2.2
```

Also in the script I included

```
( get-process -id $pid ).Path
#In all cases (even the one that fails ) it returns
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Not sure what is different between executions that does not allow loading modules from version 3.0 onwards, thats what I guess it is running Powershell 1.0 though the PSVersionTable clearly indicates it is 4.0

Just noticed that the same happened when I use the same script as a PreBuild Event in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 project

Any ideas?

Comment: `C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0` is the powershell installation home directory for *all* versions, don't let the `v1.0` folder name trick you.

Comment: As you mention using ( get-process -id $pid ).Path I see that all powershell executions point to C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Comment: Can you show us the appropriate snippet from the VagrantFile? I added support for shell arguments on provisioners to Vagrant last year. See: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/4548

Comment: Another issue that may occur in these cases is the context of the parent process. Check `[Environment]::Is64BitProcess` in the child powershell to see if one of them is running it in the wrong context.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly a result of accidentally putting `-version` after `-command`, probably something like this:

```
powershell -command -version 4.0 {import-module C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\SmbShare\SmbShare.psd1}
```

You don't exactly say where or how you're using it from vagrant so I can't say for sure, but check the place where it's being executed from to see if you've mismatched the order.

[Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) is right about the path; it's the same for every version so don't worry about that.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the case, In all scenarios I used `powershell -version 4.0 -command {import-module C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\SmbShare\SmbShare.psd1}`

Comment: In vagrant I was using `  config.trigger.before :up do
    provider = ['hyperv']
 run "powershell -version 4.0 -file 'PsTest.ps1' " 
`